# ScrollPane automatically scrolls down, but not all the way down in Scala Swing

Tags: scala, swing, scroll

I'm having an issue with a project I'm working on. The original code is too big to poste here but I wrote a short version which has the same issue.

Basically, I wrote some kind of chatbox that adds Labels containing the replies to a BoxPanel, one after another. Ideally the user wouldn't need to scroll manually, the scrolling would happen automatically and show the very last reply of the chat.

The issue is that when using `scrollBar.peer.setValue(scrollBar.peer.getMaximum)`,
the chat doesn't automatically scroll all the way down, it never shows the very last line of the chat, even after I revalidate() the chat before scrolling down.

this is what the code looks like:

```
import scala.swing._
import scala.swing.event._

class testUI extends MainFrame {

  title = "testScroll"
  preferredSize = new Dimension(400, 400)
  val chat = new BoxPanel(Orientation.Vertical)
  val inputField = new TextField {
    listenTo(mouse.clicks, this.keys)
    reactions += {
      case KeyPressed(_, Key.Enter, _, _) => if (this.text != "") { printToChat(this.text) }
    }
  }
  val scrollPanel = new ScrollPane(chat)
  var scrollBar = scrollPanel.verticalScrollBar
  val window = new BorderPanel {
    add(inputField, BorderPanel.Position.North)
    add(scrollPanel, BorderPanel.Position.Center)
  }
  contents = window

  def printToChat(s: String) {
    chat.contents += new Label(s) {
      horizontalAlignment = Alignment.Right
      border = Swing.EmptyBorder(20, 20, 0, 0) //(top, left, bottom, right)
    }
    chat.revalidate()
    scrollToBottom()
    inputField.text = ""
  }
  def scrollToBottom() {
    scrollBar.peer.setValue(scrollBar.peer.getMaximum)
  }
}

object testUI {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val ui = new testUI
    ui.visible = true
  }
}
```

Thank you very much in advance :)

EDIT: I solved my issue thanks to camickr by wrapping my previous line of code with `Swing.onEDT`:
`Swing.onEDT(scrollBar.peer.setValue(scrollBar.peer.getMaximum))`
instead of just:
`scrollBar.peer.setValue(scrollBar.peer.getMaximum)`

Comment: Wrap the code in the scrollToBottom() method in a `SwingUtilities.invokeLater()` to add the code to the end of the Event Dispatch Thread (EDT).

Comment: Thank you so much, you put me on the right track, I tried `SwingUtilities.invokeLater(scrollBar.peer.setValue(scrollBar.peer.getMaximum))` but it couldn't find the vale SwingUtilities. But using 
    `Swing.onEDT(scrollBar.peer.setValue(scrollBar.peer.getMaximum))`worked perfectly.